# Pass variable to php script with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not sure I understand how ajax works even though I read a lot about it. 
I want to run the following php if a button is clicked, without loading the page:

```
unset($checkout_fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
```

So I put the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.keep-buying-wrapper').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "url-to-the-script.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {'checked': checked},
            success: alert('success!'),

        });
    });
});
```

And in my php script:

```
if( $_POST['checked'] == 'checked' ){
        unset($checkout_fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
}
```

However nothing happen. even though the success alert is popping, `POST['checked']` is null.

Is the ajax supposes to trigger the php script? 
What if I want to send some variable to `functions.php`?

Comment: `data: {'checked': 'checked'}`

Comment: checked is a variable..

Comment: You are running AJAX on document ready, instead use `click` event

Comment: check for any error in console. are you getting any specific error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to **serialize post data first**.

**HTML code** (The id and name of checkbox is `"billing_postcode"`):

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "billing_postcode" name = "billing_postcode">
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).on('click', '#billing_postcode', function (event) {

    var data = $("#billing_postcode").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url-to-the-script.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: alert('success!'),
    })
});
```

You will get value in post array on server side and `enter code here` in **php script**:

```
if($_POST['billing_postcode'])
    unset($checkout_fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
```